# AVAssetWriterInput Video Not get

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I generate image to video using `AVAssetWriter`, my  writer settings

```
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];
videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];
```

my input image Buffer images,

[image]

but generated mov file look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generate image to video using `AVAssetWriter`, my  writer settings just modified .

```
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageView.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageView.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];
videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];
```